# It is still called your lap when you're standing up?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

This may be a stupid question, but would it be wrong to refer to my lap as my lap when I'm standing up? It doesn't sound right to me, but I don't really know what else to call it other than "quadriceps," which is really referring to the muscles, not my lap.

Comment: This is actually part of an old riddle: What disappears when you stand up?  The answer being "your lap", of course!

Comment: Even Philomena Cunq has asked [Where does your lap go when you stand up?](https://twitter.com/askmenuk/status/730502268148191234) - and if *she* doesn't know, it's probably part of what they call [*The Hard Question.*](http://www.peterrussell.com/Reality/RHTML/R15.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. When you stand up, your lap just becomes part of your legs.

> **lap** - noun
>
> the top surface of the upper part of the legs of a person who is sitting down:
>
> - Come and sit on my lap and I'll read you a story.

Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: What would you call it instead? Would "upper front thighs" work?

Comment: You could call them that if you wanted to, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, I think "thighs" is probably the best general term.  Maybe "front of the thighs" if you have to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

As a noun it is a thing which has an implied purpose to sit or rest something on.
As an adjective it is the general area on which something sits or rest.
Lapped as a verb doesn't make sense.
You can not lap or be lapped and that is the oddity.

Answer (score -2):

I believe it becomes your

> **crotch** - the part of the human body between the legs where they join the torso.

this also does depend on one's definition of "lap".

Comment: This is wrong. Let's use a pair of pants as a stand-in. The crotch is the top of the inseam and possibly the bottom of the fly. I wanted to avoid being vulgar, but let me be direct. The crotch is where a person's genitalia is.